# CSS Inheritance Issue Trying to Highlight active tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to highlight the active `<a>` however, my CSS is being overwritten.

```
#portfolio-filter li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:3px 8px 3px 8px;
    background:#8d8d8d;
}

#portfolio-filter li:hover, a.filter.active { 
    background: white; 
}

<ul id="portfolio-filter">
    <li>
        <a href="#all" class="filter active" data-filter="all" title="">All</a>
    </li>
    <li> etc... </li>
</ul>
```

The `#portfolio-filter li a` style is overwritting the  `#portfolio-filter li:hover, a.filter.active` style and not sure what I need to do to fix this.

Link: http://velnikolic.com/ramova3/?page_id=25

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `#portfolio-filter li a` is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) than `a.filter.active`. Since the background is on that `a` element, not the `li` element, your `a` background won't change even if `#portfolio-filter li:hover` is more specific.

To fix it, use something like `#portfolio-filter li a.filter.active`, which is more specific and will correctly take precedence.

As a general rule of thumb, when working with active classes, always use a similar selector as the original (non-active) definition. Otherwise, you may run into specificity issues like this one.

Here's a [useful specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The comma makes your "second" style two separate styles, remove the command and you should be fine.

ref: http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/f/comma-in-css-selectors.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution.

## portfolio-filter li a:hover, #portfolio-filter > li a.active{ background: white; }